# HDMI Type E pinout

Tags: connector, pinout, hdmi

I am looking for the pin out of the HDMI Type-E connector? It is surprisingly hard to find and as far as I know the pins 1-19 are not the same as Type-A.

What is the pin out of HDMI Type-E?

Comment: What makes you think the pinout is not the same as Type-A?

Answer (score 3):

I don't have a very good source, but as far as I have understood, the pinout is indeed the same as in Type-A connectors.

The only real source that I could find was a cable manufacturer who makes a Type-E to Type-A cable, showing that the pinout is the same in both ends at least in their cable.
[image: Cable drawing]